# unable to launch config server for mongo shard

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get the config server running for mongo shard using the following command and config file:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod2.conf
```

**mongod2.config**

```
    # Where and how to store data.
    storage:
      dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb2
      journal:
        enabled: true
    #  engine:
    #  mmapv1:
    #  wiredTiger:

    processManagement:
       pidFilePath: /srv/mongodb/db2.pid

    # where to write logging data.
    systemLog:
      destination: file
      logAppend: true
      path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

    # network interfaces
    net:
      port: 27019
      bindIp: 127.0.0.1

    processManagement:
       fork: true

    #security:
    #  authorization: enabled

replication:
   replSetName: configReplSet

    sharding:
      clusterRole: configsvr
```

When I run the command above, I get the following output (with no log output in the mongo logs):

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 14246
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
```

I am running mongo v3.2.2 on ubuntu v14.  The port 27019 is not bound by another process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused since I never created a separate data directory.  I saw better error messages when I ran the following:

```
mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb2 --port 27019
```

This command gave better error messages (it showed that the data directory was not present etc.).  This helped solve the issue and I was able to run the config server (output below):

```
2016-06-29T12:21:30.216-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=16060 port=27019 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb2 64-bit host=abcdefghi
2016-06-29T12:21:30.216-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.0
```